# Operator |= for a boolean in C++

Tags: c++, operators, boolean

I stumbled upon the following construction in C++:

```
bool result = false;
for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
  result |= TryAndDoSomething(i);
}
```

I supposed that this `|=` was a shortcut for the OR operator, and that `result` would equal `true` in the end if at least one of these calls to `TryAndDoSomething` had returned `true`.

But now I am wondering if more than one call can actually return `true`. Indeed if we extend the operation as:

```
result = result || TryAndDoSomething(i);
```

Then the method will be called only if return evaluated to `false`, that is, if no other call before returned `true`. Thus after one call returning `true`, no other call will be done.

Is this the correct interpretation?

Comment: You can test it easily. I just did, and it looks like all the calls are made, not just the first.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

On booleans, `|` yields the same result as `||`, but doesn't short-circuit.  The right operand of `|=` is always evaluated.

Comment: @MooingDuck: This question only asks about booleans.  I don't know whether the OP knows about bitwise-OR, and it doesn't appear important to what he's doing.

Comment: Id be happier with the answer if you said how they were different for non-booleans since the OP obviously doesnt know about bitwise-or (corrected typo)

Answer (score 51):

It's [bitwise OR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) assignment, not short-circuited OR evaluation.

**It is equivalent to:**

```
result = result | TryAndDoSomething(i);
```

**Not:**

```
result = result || TryAndDoSomething(i);
```

Comment: Probably the most accurate answer! +1

Answer (score 8):

The only difference in this context between `x |= f()` (bitwise OR) and `x = x || f()` (logical OR) is that the latter is short-circuiting. In the former, `f()` will be executed `n` times—unless of course `f()` throws an exception, but that’s another story.

In the `||` version, `f()` will no longer be called once `x` becomes `true`. C++ does not have a `||=` operator, but it is important to understand that `|=` and `||=` (if it existed) would have different semantics because of this. `|=` is not just a replacement for the missing `||=`.

As a side note, provided you are using `bool`, the bitwise operation *is* safe, because the standard specifies that `true` and `false` convert to the integers `1` and `0`, respectively. So the only difference in this case is eager versus lazy evaluation.

Comment: @MooingDuck: True. Edited to restrict to the OP’s context.

Comment: All you have to tell him is his interpretation is invalid.  |= is the bitwise OR as you point out.  So x |= 1 is the same as doing x = x | 1.  X ||= 1; will not compile.

Comment: @Ramhound: Read the question again.

Answer (score 1):

`result |= Try()` is short for `result = result | Try();`.  The `||` operator you seem to understand, but the `|` operator is quite different.  It's name is bitwise or (as opposed to logical or).  It has the same affect as if it performed `a=a||b` on each *bit*  of the operands, and doesnt have the quick-bailout thing that logical and/or have. (It's also *crazy* fast; as fast or faster than addition).  The other bitwise operations are `&` (bitwise and: `a=a&&b` on each bit), and `^` (bitwise xor: `a=(a!=b)` on each bit).

Comment: @BenVoigt: Copy-Paste FTL!  Thanks!  Fix'd.