# In C#, what does '|=' do?

Tags: c#, operators

I can't seem to Google it - doesn't appear to like the syntax in the search string.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: 7 answers within a minute ;) -- anyway it's worth mentioning that x |= y is not *exactly* the same as x = x | y, in that side effects etc. distinguish the two in certain cases, but the concept is still there.

Comment: Basically a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021049/operator-for-a-boolean-in-c/9021094#9021094

Comment: @ChrisShain it's a bit different because C# and C++ have different semantics for the expansion of a `|=` IIRC.

Comment: @JaredPar true, I always forget the limiting of side-effects diff.

Comment: I also think you can override it in C++, but not in C#, if memory serves.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is a bit wise assignment.  It's roughly shorthand for the following

```
x |= y;
x = x | y;
```

Note: It's not truly the above because the C# spec guarantees the side effects of `x` only occur once.  So if `x` is a complex expression there is a bit of fun code generated by the compiler to ensure that the side effects only happen once.

```
Method().x |= y;
Method().x = Method().x | y;  // Not equivalent

var temp = Method();
temp.x = temp.x | y;  // Pretty close
```

Comment: if the left side is a property, the getter is also only ever called once, which is the same principle (since a property basically is a get method).

Comment: @Servy even more fun to consider: `(await x).SomeMethod().y |= z;`  Or my personal favorite `(await x)[await y].z += await a;`

Comment: @JarredPar That's where I draw the line and slap the developer that writes such a line.  As funny as it is, it deserves to be on more than one line.

Comment: @JarredPar wow, your edit is far more scary; the first one I could at least wrap my head around.  +1 for the lols.  Is that an addition `+=` or an event subscribing `+=`?

Comment: @Servy unfortunately as a compiler developer I can't stop the guy who writes that kind of code. You have to make sure the terrible code functions correctly

Comment: Ah, the easy life of a LOB developer ;)

Answer (score 5):

The expression `a |= b` is equivalent to the assignment `a = a | b`, where `|` is the bitwise OR operator.*

<sup>* Not entirely, but close enough for most purposes.</sup>

Comment: It's not *exactly* equivalent because the C# compiler guarantees the side effects of `a` only happen once in the `|=` case

Comment: @JaredPar: Okay :) But if you take *a* and *b* as expressions and not code, then yes, it is true.

Answer (score 3):

It's like `+=`, but with the binary OR

```
int x = 5;
x |= 6;  // x is now 7: 5 | 6
```

You can also do others like `&=`, `/=`, `*=`, etc.  Pretty much any binary (two argument) operator

Answer (score 3):

|= is a bitwise OR assignment operator. Check out the msdn documentation here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5f1zzaw(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: +1 for the link, -1 for a description that is misleading.  | is a bitwise OR operator, |= is a bitwise OR operator combined with an assignment.

Answer (score 1):

`a |= b` is semantically the same as `a = a | b`

Answer (score 1):

you gonna find the answer
[here on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5f1zzaw.aspx)

```
x |= y
```

is the same as

```
x = x | y
```

Answer (score 0):

In C and other languages following C syntax conventions, such as C++, Perl, Java and C#, (a | b) denotes a bitwise or; whilst a double vertical bar (a || b) denotes a (short-circuited) logical or.

Comment: this is not a bitwise or but a bitwise or with assignment back to the left hand side storage location